# mobile comments space stops working at line end

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

I noticed this a while ago, but only now I realized the pattern and can tell when it's happening.

When commenting using mobile version, if reaching a line-break, i.e. the next word will be on a new line, pressing space doesn't work. You can press as many times as you want, you just stay in place, at the end of the last word.

The workaround is writing the next word  (or first character) right after the last word (so they are joined), manually going back in between them and *then* pressing space, which is tedious and annoying

I'm using a Galaxy S I, using default browser, haven't tested behaviour on others.

Comment: It's insanely irritating isn't it

Comment: @RichardTingle yes it is. Sorry for the dup, I did not find that post when searching. Could you edit it to include Galaxy S I as well?

Comment: In which case a dupe was necessary. Have added the S1 data